# What is the simplest way to write to an ip address from within a C program?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, shell

I am upgrading a filter program written in C.  The program is meant to receive a data-stream from a serial port modify it slightly; then send it on to the ip address of a tcp to rs485 wireless tunnel.  Currently the program relies on i/o redirection from a shell script -- it is evoked like this:

```
./packetfilter </dev/ttyS4 >/dev/tcp/10.0.50.101/4660
```

The shell gives me tcp/ip for free.  Now I need both stderr and stdout.
What is the simplest way to write my serial data to a network address?

Answer (score 3):

It's very easy to open a socket in C, but most code you find is using ugly, deprecated methods that make it look hard. Here's the correct way:

```
struct addrinfo *ai;
int fd;
if (getaddrinfo(host_string, port_string, 0, &ai)) goto failed;
fd = socket(ai->ai_family, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (connect(fd, ai->ai_addr, ai->ai_addrlen)) goto failed2;
```

Fill in the error handling.

Comment: Thank you. That looks very doable.  What do I #include?

Comment: `<netdb.h>` and `<sys/socket.h>`

Comment: You should also call `freeaddrinfo(ai)` if you're not going to keep the address around after you're done, but you might want to keep it in case you need to reconnect later.

Comment: In the code above the first line should be: struct adrinfo * ai;.  It needs to be a pointer

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the IP address at the "dots", and form a 32-bit integer (assuming that you're only worried about IPV4 - if IPV6, you have more work ahead of you...).

Each "dotted" number will become one byte in yout IP addr5ess - so that in hexadecimal, your address in the example will become 0x0A003265

(0x0A = 10, 00=0, 0x32=50, 0x65=101, if I didn't screw up)

THEN pass the 32 bit integer throputh the htons function so that it is put "in the correct" (network) order (htons converts from host to network byte order).  Plug the result into your socket, and you're all set.

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking at this prototype: int getaddrinfo(const char *node, const char *service, const struct addrinfo *hints, struct addrinfo **res);. This is accepting the address as a string. Am I missing something?

Comment: The answer you gave is exactly the sort of old, ugly way you *shouldn't* be doing this. IPv4 space ran out this year. In the next few years, IPv6 support will likely be a make-or-break issue for applications; there will be a large audience that simply can't use them if they don't support IPv6. So don't go writing this old ugly style code where you have to think about converting binary address formats yourself. Just call `getaddrinfo` and everything is done for you, and IPv4, IPv6, and even IPv7 ;-) will work just fine with no effort.

Comment: IPv8 you mean; IPv7 will be(?) a strictly experimental protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect to a higher FD, then use [`write(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write).

```
./packetfilter </dev/ttyS4 3>/dev/tcp/10.0.50.101/4660
```

Comment: This answer is not C, it's bash. The fake `/dev/tcp` is a bash extension and it's a source of much trouble. Some distros disable it because it yields a nonconformant shell and potentially creates security risks in a restricted chroot shell-only environment.

Comment: @R..: It's also what the OP is currently using anyway.

Comment: Yes, thank you. But I'd like to pass the ip address in on the command line and handle the output from within the program.  I have never done network programming and will learn if necessary.  But if there is a simple way to write a byte stream to ip -- duplicating what is currently being done by bash -- it would help for me to know how.

Comment: There is no simple equivalent. Writing data to a socket is easy enough, but setting up the socket in the first place requires a few steps.

Comment: Yes but OP was looking for a better way. OP's approach is also very bad because if the connection goes down there's no way for the program to attempt to re-establish it.

Comment: I can certainly see why they might drop it, but I don't see what you mean by nonconformant.